# Questions about Local notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, notifications, foreground

I'm working on a project on iOS 7, 8 that use a lot of notifications (Remote, Local). I have some questions about Local Notification.

- I'm using Local Notification to schedule an alarm or a count-down. As I know, the use of NSTimer is not really a good choice since it has only up to 10' in background & if the app process is killed it doesn't work anymore. Local Notification is managed by iOS but I have to accept its alert when the app is not in foreground. There's nothing like silent local notification (local notification without alert, sound or badge and app still knows about it although it's in background). Am I right ?
- Let's assume that there're some simple local notifications in Notification Center, scheduled by our app. Normally when I touch on a notification to see it in my app, the others remain present until we interact with them. In some cases that I haven't figured out, all other notifications are removed from the Notification Center. Does anyone encounter this & understand why ?
- I find the interactive notification feature in iOS very limited. I want to change the title of a defined UIMutableUserNotificationAction button & add an image for it, like I can do with UIButton. So the question is : Is it possible to customize the UI of an action button ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no correspondence in silent notification using local notifications.
The number of the visible notification in the notification center is a user decision, the user in Settings can decide to set a different number or decide to do not show them in notification center as well. As for the first point no. 
The third point is not clear, you can set the image you want for a remote just put in the payload the right name, local notifications use the app icon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There's some misunderstanding here. I updated my questions. Hope they're more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no silent notification for Local Notification. The user has to click to the notification to open your App.
2. I suppose that the associated application has deleted those notifications programmatically. Else, those notifications must stay in the notification center.
3. You cannot add image to action buttons but just the titles.

Answer (score 0):

I tried more than two weeks to do the same. I had to show notification after 2 hrs even if the use doesn't click the notification. But the repetition facility is well handled in objective C. I could have created multiple local notification but it will also violates the total number of 64 notifications. Apple needs to improved the same.